# adding Generated modules in POM

Tags: maven

I am trying to create a multi module project like below.

```
root
  p1
  p2/p1_generated module
  p2/p3
  p2/p4
```

When I build p1 folder it will generate p2/p1_generated module & it will be part of the compete build.

My pom goes as below

```
root_pom
========
<groupId>com.demo.dh.test</groupId>
<artifactId>dh-parent</artifactId>

<modules>
    <module>Design</module>
    <module>Projects</module>
</modules>

Design/pom.xml
==============
<groupId>com.demo.dh.test.impl</groupId>
<artifactId>adh-implementation-design</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.dh.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dh-parent</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>../Projects/Generated</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            ..custom plugin
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Projects/pom.xml
==============
<artifactId>adh-implementation-projects</artifactId>
<groupId>com.demo.dh.test.impl</groupId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.dh.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dh-parent</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modules>
    <module>Generated</module>
    <module>package</module>
</modules>
```

I am unable to run clean install as it says

> > Child module Projects\Generated of Projects\pom.xml does not exist

Any help on how to implement this.

Comment: Please show your pom file and the complete error output

Comment: Updated the pom

Comment: First I would suggest to remove things like `<sourceDirectory>..</sourceDirectory>`and `<outputDirectory>..</outputDirectory>` from your pom file until you really know what you are doing ...Can you please make an example project on Github or alike ...